# How can i make list tallying the number of times each number is shown

Tags: python

```
from random import randint 
roll_again = "yes"
while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    Num = input ("How Many Times Would u like to roll the Dice?")
    for i in range(int(Num)):
        print(randint(1,6))

roll_again = input("Roll the dices again?")
```

How can I make it so that it makes a tally of each number is printed it's for a school class internal so I really need some help it's in python so please help

Comment: The last line of your code is incorrectly indented.

Comment: Ok but how can i make a telly of all the numbers that is printed?